# Eclipse won't produce xml file in layout , or a java file in src when making android application

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

When i make a new Android application project,  , it does not give me the xml file in the layout folder under res , and does not give me any java files in the src source folder. Just don't know what to do , have uninstalled and re installed the entire of eclipse and all its sdks , have no clue whatsoever now , really disappointed that everything has come to a halt and its just not working . Help please if you can cheers

Comment: Yeh i go on new, other , android application project , and follow the steps

Comment: So disheartening , because yesterday i did those steps and it worked it created the correct files , but now i have changed some of the sdks , and tried to start new one and it simply does not created the xml file or the java file. And i also cant get my bloody phone to work either after following online advice

Comment: Did I misunderstand or is it a simple question. It is not supposed to give you any xml or java file. You will create that files. Which files are you talking about?

Comment: do you get a *src* folder?

Comment: this is the video i have followed , i follow these step and as you can see he automatically generates the xml file under the res layout foler and the java file under the src folder , but i dont for some reason       http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIKl8PX838E

Comment: Ok sorry its at the start of the next video in the series number 5

Comment: Actually I learned my self android from these tutorials, its very great, but what folders did you get?

Comment: I got the src folder , and i got the layout folder , but there was just nothing in them , whereas on the videos , he has the files already there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to uninstall Eclipse or the SDK, it's a matter of wiring things up in the right order.  That video is using a slightly older version of Eclipse and the ADT plugins.

1. Download and install the Android SDK.
2. Launch the SDK Manager and install the latest platform tools and platform SDK level. Get the samples, docs, and source package while you're at it.  You don't necessarily need the emulator images unless you want to use them.
3. Make sure the SDK/tools, SDK/platform-tools, SDK/build-tools are on your PATH.  Ensure by opening a terminal (Command Prompt) and typing 'adb devices'.
4. Download and unpack Eclipse. If you don't have an existing Eclipse installation, it's best to use the one that Google provides that has the ADT plugins already built in.
5. If you have an existing Eclipse and you want to use it, add the Google update site and install the ADT plugins.  Restart Eclipse.
6. Go to Window/Preferences in Eclipse and point the Android SDK at the top folder where the SDK is.
7. Try to create a sample application with File->New->Project...  From there, expand Android and choose Android Sample Project.  I usually go with Skeleton.

[image: File Menu on Windows]

[image: New Android Sample Project]

If you can get this far, you have everything set up.  If it's still not creating the src and layouts, check that the Create Activity box is selected on the New Android Project dialog so it will give you the basic files you need.

[image: New Android Project wizard]

Comment: Thanks guys for all your great answers , just managed to get it working, had 2 versions of eclipse downloaded on my computer , both the same eclipse icon , but one of them would load a program that looked identical to eclipse but had a different header and name called android development kit or something in green and then the other was eclipse , anyway , it has generated the files now , which is good , although a lot more code is in those files than in the video tutorial files , but i guess ill figure that out later , thanks so much for all answers , cheers

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Verify Android SDK is in place. In eclipse go to Window > Preferences > Android. Make sure you see some Target names there.
2. If SDk is at place, Go to File > New > Other > Android > Android Application Project > Next
3. Fill out the App name, It will automatically give you the Package Name and Project Name.
4. Press Next till you get Finish.

You will see the "Hello World" implemented android app in your project explorer.

Comment: Ok will just give a try although i think i have done that already one second

Comment: Thanks guys for all your great answers , just managed to get it working, had 2 versions of eclipse downloaded on my computer , both the same eclipse icon , but one of them would load a program that looked identical to eclipse but had a different header and name called android development kit or something in green and then the other was eclipse , anyway , it has generated the files now , which is good , although a lot more code is in those files than in the video tutorial files , but i guess ill figure that out later , thanks so much for all answers , cheers

Answer (score 0):

In New Project wizard there is a step in which you have an option to Create Activity, To have a default activity you should tick that option.

By the way cleaning the project (Project->Clean) might help

Comment: Thanks guys for all your great answers , just managed to get it working, had 2 versions of eclipse downloaded on my computer , both the same eclipse icon , but one of them would load a program that looked identical to eclipse but had a different header and name called android development kit or something in green and then the other was eclipse , anyway , it has generated the files now , which is good , although a lot more code is in those files than in the video tutorial files , but i guess ill figure that out later , thanks so much for all answers , cheers